# Outlook: how to configure to use another server for outgoing mail?

Tags: email, smtp, pop3

I have a client that has problems with his current outgoing mail provider. It seems he uses a server for incoming mail and another server (another provider) for outgoing. But since the outgoing mail service is randomly unavailable, he wants to change to my servers.

Is there a way to configure his outlook to use my MediaTemple servers only for outgoing mail **without making changes to the domain configuration** (DNS nor NameServer changes)? if so, how?

Comment: Explain "domain configuration".

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Well... why not use the incoming mail providers SMTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your SMTP server to allow relaying from the client ip address(es), or alternately configure your SMTP server to allow authenticated relaying and create a user account (or user accounts) for your client to use to authenticate to your SMTP server, then confugure the client Outlook settings to use your SMTP server for outgoing email.

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure your smtp server so that it accepts to relay mails for his domain and configure his email client to use your smtp server.